# Flutter MaterialApp TextField perspective transform not rendering properly

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I have a simple `MaterialApp` wih `Scaffold` wrapped in `Transfrom` widget to render the app slightly rotated on x and y axis. It works fine as long as I don't have `TextField` in the `Scaffold` body.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(TestApp());

class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestAppState createState() => TestAppState();
}

class TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(home: LandingScreen());
  }
}

class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Transform(
      transform: Matrix4.identity()
        ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001) // perspective
        ..rotateX(.4)
        ..rotateY(.4),
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Title")),
        body: Center(
          child: Text("test data"), // <-- replace Text with TextField here
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This renders as follow[image]

If I replace `Text` inside `Scaffold` body with `TextField` then it renders as follows.

[image]

I am expecting to see the `AppBar` at the top and the `TextField` rendered at the center of the the screen.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: It renders correctly for me. What code are you using in the body?

Comment: it's works fine for me. please add some code.

Comment: @chemamolins did you replace  `child: Text("test data")` with `child: TextField()`

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that.

Comment: It works in an Android emulator and in the iOS simulator.

Comment: @chemamolins thanks, not sure what caused it. after upgrading to latest version of flutter, it started working for me.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I believe the issue in question was fixed here: https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/5693